# action script: understand about variable

Tags: actionscript-3

i am learning Action scrip. i reading a function in ac, but i am not full understand it yet.
My main question is `key` variable: what is value of `key` and what is `key;` mean?
Thanks

```
private function processXML(event:Event) : void
{
    var infoXML:XML;
    var clearText:String;
    var key:String;  
    var e:* = event;
    clearText = e.target.data;
        try
        {
            infoXML = new XML(clearText);
            if (infoXML.movie == undefined && infoXML.error == undefined)
            {
                key;
                clearText = RC4.decrypt(e.target.data, key);
            }
        }
        catch (error:Error)
        {
            if (infoXML.movie == undefined && infoXML.error == undefined)
            {
                key;
                clearText = RC4.decrypt(e.target.data, key);
            }
        }
        infoXML = new XML(clearText);
}
```

Comment: Key doesn't appear to have any value assigned to it in this code, and `key;` doesn't do anything. Is this all the code?

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, that is main of this method. it has some codes below this but i clear it.

Comment: The `key` variable it's a encryption key for RC4 algorithm. But in your code there is no initialization of `key` variable.

Comment: `key;` means "take the value of the variable `key` and do nothing with it", so it is just a useless operation.